# Can't add user to database

Tags: java, php, android, api, android-volley

I'm developing android app and use this script to add user to MySQL database the problem is I can't add user to the database when I test  the script on postman and android app the response always is :

> {"OKCode":0,"message":"Required field(s) is missing"}

and here is the php script :

```
    <?php

      header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 
      // array for JSON response
       $response = array();

       // include db connect class
       require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

       // check for post data
       if (
            isset($_POST['student_name']) &&
            isset($_POST['id_school']) &&
            isset($_POST['u_password']) &&
            isset($_POST['id_number']) &&
            isset($_POST['licence']) &&
            isset($_POST['phone'])&&
            isset($_POST['username'])
         ) {

         $student_name  = $_POST['student_name'];
         $id_school     = $_POST['id_school'];
         $u_password    = $_POST['u_password'];
         $id_number     = $_POST['id_number'];
         $licence       = $_POST['licence'];
         $phone         = $_POST['phone'];
         $username      = $_POST['username'];


         $id ;

         // connecting to db
         $db = new DB_CONNECT();
         $con = $db->_connect();
         if (!userExists($con, $username)) {
         if (insertIntoUser($con, $username, $id_school, $u_password)) {
        # when the student insert into user add The student to Student 
       table
        # whit the last update id 
        if (insertIntoStudent($con, $id, $id_school, $student_name, $licence, $id_number, $phone)) {
            $response["OKCode"] = 1;
            $response["message"] = "done";

        } else {

            $response["OKCode"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "fail";
        }
    } else {
        $response["OKCode"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "fail";
    }

}else {
    $response["OKCode"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "This account is already in users";
}
}else {
$response["OKCode"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";
}
echo json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);


/* check if username is not in the user tabel for this 
   username is the id_number of the student 
 */
function userExists($con, $username)
{
$query = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = ?";
if ($stmt = $con->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->fetch();
    if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
        $stmt->close();
        return true;
    }
    $stmt->close();
 }

return false;
}

function insertIntoUser($con, $username, $id_school, $u_password)
{
$account_type = 2;
$insertQuery  = "INSERT INTO users (id_school, username, u_password, 
account_type) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = $con->prepare($insertQuery);
if (
    $stmt &&
    $stmt->bind_param("isii", $id_school, $username, $u_password, 
 $account_type) &&
    $stmt->execute()
) {
     global $id;
     $id = $stmt->insert_id;
     $stmt->close();
    return true;
}
$stmt->close();
return false;
}

 function insertIntoStudent($con, $id, $id_school, $student_name, $licence, 
  $id_number, $phone)
 {
  $insertQuery  = "INSERT INTO student(id, id_school, student_name, licence, 
id_number, phone) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = $con->prepare($insertQuery);
if (
    $stmt && $stmt->bind_param("iissii", $id, $id_school, $student_name, 
  $licence, $id_number, $phone) &&
    $stmt->execute()
) {
    return true;
    $stmt->close();
}
$stmt->close();
return false;
}
```

[the php script](https://gist.github.com/PalMoh/64cdab99ee7eb775731ff1baf845b5b0)

Screen shot for postman [image: postman screen shoot]

and this the java code `
         private void addNewStudent() {

```
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, 
     ADD_NEW_STUDENT_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            pBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnAddStudent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            isSelected = false;
            radioGroup.clearCheck();

            Log.d("MyTag", response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String,String> stringMap = new HashMap<>();
            stringMap.put("student_name",studentName);
            stringMap.put("id_school",idSchool);
            stringMap.put("u_password",password);
            stringMap.put("id_number",idNumber);
            stringMap.put("licence",type);
            stringMap.put("phone",phoneNumber);
            stringMap.put("username","hp");

            return stringMap;
        }
    };

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request,ADD_STUDENT_TAG);

}`
```

Comment: The PHP code should be here, not on a linked page. Output your `POST` and see what you actually have. Also `isset` can take multiple values, you shouldn't have multiple calls like that.

Comment: @user3783243 like this (isset($_POST['student_name'],$_POST['id_school'],$_POST['id_school'],$_POST['u_password'],$_POST['id_number'],$_POST['licence'],$_POST['phone'],$_POST['username']))

Comment: Since you have the same problem inside postman, the problem is in your PHP code. Can you var_dump($_POST) to see what inside?

Comment: @catcon array(0) {
}
{"success":0,"message":"Required field(s) is missing"} and when change $_POST to $_GET it work in postman but in android doesn't

Comment: You are adding the values to the query parameters, but in a POST request you have to add them to the body instead.

Answer (score -2):

> the response always is : {"OKCode":0,"message":"Required field(s) is missing"}

```php
if (
    isset($_POST['student_name']) &&
    isset($_POST['id_school']) &&
    isset($_POST['u_password']) &&
    isset($_POST['id_number']) &&
    isset($_POST['licence']) &&
    isset($_POST['phone'])&&
    isset($_POST['username'])
) {
    # (..)
}else {
    $response["OKCode"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing"; # <----
}
```

So one or more of your $_POST fields don't exist. Try a `print_r($_POST)` to see what's in POST..

Comment: here what i got Array
(
)
{"OKCode":0,"message":"Required field(s) is missing"}

Comment: So this means nothing seems to be getting posted. Looking at your postman screenshot that's strange. What's in `print_r($_GET)`? Note you can also make your app use both GET and POST at the same time with `$_REQUEST`

Comment: when i change $_POST to $_GET or $_REQUEST  it works and in android app using Android Asynchronous Http Client library but why it doesn't work when using $_POST